# Find initial conidtion in order for the solution to be periodic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the following non homogeneous ode system:

> $x'(t)=Ax+f(t)=\begin{bmatrix}2 &1 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix} x(t) + \begin{bmatrix} \sin t \\  \cos^2t \end{bmatrix} $.

Find $x(0)=x_0$ in order for the solution $x(t)$ to be periodic.

Looking at matrix $A$ we see that has a repeated eigenvalue $\lambda=2$ and one eigenvector $u^T=[1 \ 0]$. Thus we have a degenerate node that diverges. Furthermore

> $x(t)=e^{At}\left[ x_0 + \int_0^t e^{-A\tau} f(\tau) \, d\tau \right]$

I can take $x(0)=x(T)$ and get

> $(I-e^{-T A})x_0=-\int_0^T e^{-A\tau} f(\tau) \, d\tau$

From $x'(0)=x'(T)$ I can get that $T=2\pi$ and since $(I-e^{AT})$ is invertible we get

> $x_0=-(I-e^{-2\pi A})^{-1}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-A\tau} f(\tau) \, d\tau$

Is this approach correct? I feel that something is not sticking.

Comment: You can also solve this component-wise, the second equation is scalar in $x_2$, find its periodic solution and insert into the first equation. This can then likewise solved as scalar equation in $x_1$.

Comment: @Moo The integral form suited me better, since I found it to be okay. Nevertheless, I used the comment to see another way to solve this.

Comment: I didn't get that. If we assume $x(t)=x(t+T)$ then $x'(t)=x'(t+T)\implies Ax(t)+f(t)=Ax(t+T)+f(t+T)\implies f(t)=f(t+T)\implies T=2\pi$

Comment: I havent calculated it properly, but doing in on the fly I would say $x_0\approx [0.075 \ 0.375]$